# Where it is decided to what type DB fields are converted?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, weblogic, ojdbc

Old code has stopped working in one environment. Following code gives exception java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to java.lang.String:

```
List l = em.CreateNativeQuery(q).getResultList();
String s = (String) ((Object[])l.get(0))[0];
```

The reason is that in all environments char(1) DB field is converted to char[1] which could be cast to String. In one environment char(1) DB field is converted to Character which cannot be cast to String. I could fix it but I have following question. Where it is decided to what type DB fields are converted ? This app works (and in one case doesn't work) with Oracle 19, Weblogic, jodbc8, java 8, hibernate 3*

Comment: The JDBC driver is in charge of such conversions between the database and the java application.
Check if you are using the same driver in your different environments.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that for such conversions responsible is hibernate.
In my case problem was in tables field definition. In all correctly working environments field has type VARCHAR2(1) but in not working env type is CHAR(1)

Comment: The question was "Where it is decided to what type DB fields are converted?" This does not appear to be an answer to that question and should probably be a comment or an edit to the question.